# Close Content Dialog in Code Behind

Tags: uwp

I have a content dialog with a textbox and I would like to close the dialog when I hit enter in the textbox. Is there a way to achieve that without click on the primary button?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ContentDialog.Hide() hide the dialog, then the call of ShowAsync returned. I can't guarantee that the call is same with primary button, but it's enough for me. :)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.hide

Answer (score 1):

When you show the dialog you need to keep the returned asynchronous operation and then you can pass that into the dialog so it can be cancelled at any time. Only after that do you actually await it.

```
IAsyncOperation<ContentDialogResult> operation = dialog.ShowAsync();
dialog.AsyncInfo = operation;
await operation;
```

Add a public property to your ContentDialog class called AsyncInfo with type IAsyncInfo. When you want the dialog to be removed you just call AsyncInfo.Cancel inside your ContentDialog implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The trap I fell into was responding to ContentDialogResult like so:

```
    ContentDialogResult result = await cldEdit.ShowAsync();
    if (result == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
    {
        DoTextChange();
    }
```

Instead ignore the result and call your function based on the events instead.

So, add code for the textbox KeyUp event and the PrimaryButtonClick event:

```
private void txtEdit_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Key) {
        case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter:
            if (cldEdit.IsPrimaryButtonEnabled) {
                cldEdit.Hide();
                DoTextChange();
            }
            break;
        case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Escape:
            cldEdit.Hide();
            break;
    }

}

private void cldEdit_PrimaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
{
    DoTextChange();
}
```